# Magento change hosting

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, import, server

Today I changed one magento to another server. But I have one problem:

In the new server, all my products have automatically set:

- special price to 0.00
- all data fields to: 30/11/2000

In categories the field:

- Layered Navigation Price Step is set to 0.00
- All data field to 30/11/2000

I put this in the top of sql import field:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;
```

And this in the bottom:

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;
```

If not the import give me errros.

What is the problem?

Edit:

SQL dumb:

```
CREATE TABLE `de5frs_catalog_product_flat_1`
...
`special_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'special_price',
`special_to_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'special_to_date',
`tax_class_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'tax_class_id',
...
```

And the data table are empty.

Comment: Did you do a reindex after importing?

Comment: Did that solve it you mean?

Comment: No, sorry, I mean that i reindexing before posting here. Sorry. I still searching a solution.

Comment: Did you check the database dump which you created before if the values in there are right? How did you create the dump which was imported?

Comment: I add some dumb info on the post. I use XCloner to do the backup (files and DB).

Comment: Ok, I found the problem! XCloner does wrong the DB dump. I used the MyPHPAdmin export and all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would export all products before moving to new server as well as backup the database.
Then I would import the database like you did and if this doesn't help, I would import all the products from previous exported file.

**From System > Import/Export > Import**